# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException geolocator package which works fine on android but not in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, geolocator

Here is my code to fetch location which is working on android but in IOS its showing error

`Position position = await Geolocato.getCurrentPosition( desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);`

ERROR:
`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getCurrentPosition on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator)`

Package : https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Comment: run 

     `flutter clean` 
   `flutter pub get`

then 

then go to ios folder of the project and run

    `pod init`
    `pod install`
  then try to run the project

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh Thank you, But i already tried that one it showing same error

Comment: have you add permission string in `info.plist` file?

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh Yes added

Comment: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/745 check this